# Define a range point using text value in cell

Tags: vba, excel

In WS2, cell B2, I have the formula `=CONCATENATE("B3:B", 'ABC'!N4)`. It displays the text "B3:B24". I would like to define this as a range on VBA which will copy onto the last row of data in column A. Alternatively, I also have the value 24 in WS2 cell C4. I've tried multiple methods but I can't quite get it to work

```
Sub Sample()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rngX As Range
Dim CellRangeDefine As Variant
Dim CellRange As Range
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet

Set WS1 = Worksheets("ABC")
Set WS2 = Worksheets("123")

numFiles = WS2.Range("C4").Value

CellRange = Range("B3", Range("B" & numFiles.Value))

CellRange.Copy Destination:=WS2.Range("A" & _
                                 WS2.Range("A" & WS2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to:

```
Set CellRange = WS2.Range(WS2.Range("B2").Value)
```

This does not have any error checking, so assumes that `B2` contains a valid range address. Remember to `Set` the `CellRange` otherwise it will just put the value of the right hand side into `CellRange` (default behaviour/method for range).

Also - **always** use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules. This will have picked up the error with `numfiles`, particularly how you tried to use `numfiles.value` which does not make sense after you had passed the value of a cell into it!